# Mic isn't working in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, sound, bluetooth, microphone

I have a problem that at first looks similar to the one here:

[How to use a bluetooth headset mic in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605075/how-to-use-a-bluetooth-headset-mic-in-ubuntu/605366#605366)

After working on this for hours, I was grateful to come across that webpage, giving hope. My Agptek headset (no Dongle -- just Bluetooth direct to a Lenovo Thinkpad) worked fine on Windows 8.2. When I changed the O/S on the machine to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, I got symptoms similar to those at the above link: the headphones only worked in A2DP, and, if I change the input sound source (from Thinkpad's internal mic to Agptek's mic) then the input and output sound both stop working. So, in Ubuntu my headset is basically reduced to a pair of headphones, with no mic.

Interesting to learn at the link above that HSP/HFP has to work in order for the mic to work. I'm still new to this.

The output of lsusb is:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 5986:0299 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21f3 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 045e:00db Microsoft Corp. Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 V1.0
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 1a7c:0192 Evoluent 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have PulseAudio Volume Control and I use the standard Bluetooth system that comes with Ubuntu. I tried Blueman to get around this problem, but that didn't work so I restored the desktop to default settings again.

Any ideas on next steps? Thanks very much.

Comment: In a terminal, type `alsamixer`, select Capture (mic) by pressing F4, then select the soundcard with F6, and check if the mic volume is on. Use keyboard arrows to move around and change volume.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! When I pressed F4, I got "This sound device does not have any capture controls." When I pressed F6, three options appeared:

Comment: (-) default, (0) HDA ATI HDMI, (1) HD-Audio Generic

Comment: When I selected '0' nothing happened but when I selected '1' I was able to increase the 'Mic Boost' from above 0, using the keyboard arrows.

Comment: Unfortunately the mic still wasn't working after that. In sound settings, I then tried changing the headset output from AD2P Sink to HSP/HFP and back but this didn't help. Thanks again for any other ideas, and please forgive the odd paragraphing above -- I'm new here and don't know how to force line breaks in Comments.