# How to use mic on bluetooth headset - Kubuntu 19.10

Tags: kubuntu, bluetooth, microphone

#### My Issue

I am using the Jabra Elite 65t with Kubuntu 19.10. Sound works fine, but I need to also use the microphone. I've searched through settings and forums to no success. Is there a driver that I need to download or a hidden option somewhere?

#### Some things I've tried/looked at

- I've looked at [How to use a bluetooth headset mic in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605075/how-to-use-a-bluetooth-headset-mic-in-ubuntu), but I don't use a Bluetooth dongle.
- I've tried PulseAudio, but that doesn't have an option to allow the headset mic
- I've tried Blueman, but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot this post existed

Audio Applet > Audio Settings > Audio > Advanced > Device > Change option

Headset Unit (HSP/HFP) enables the microphone, but decreases sound quality immensly

Comment: Is there a way to use mic while having no effect on the sound quality?

Comment: No, there is not enough bandwidth for bluetooth to transmit both playing audio and recorded sound perfectly.

Comment: So this isn't a problem with ubuntu in general, right?

Comment: no it is not...

Comment: oh okay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PipeWire](https://pipewire.org/) if you want to use headphones over bluetooth. PipeWire has

- [mSBC](https://www.redpill-linpro.com/techblog/2021/05/31/better-bluetooth-headset-audio-with-msbc.html) codec which provides superior quality over the HSP codec available with Pulseaudio.
- lower latency
- is the forward looking sound server for linux.

Unfortunately the HSP mSBC sound quality is still worse than A2DP (which also works perfectly with PipeWire), but you can easily change it with your mixer / audio settings.

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-pipewire-on-ubuntu-linux